# Why this answer has been deleted when it's a suitable answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

A year before I posted a question ie [Whats the best plugin to fetch Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, Twitter and Facebook contact list in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311132/whats-the-best-plugin-to-fetch-gmail-yahoo-hotmail-twitter-and-facebook-conta/6311360#6311360)

Yesterday, I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12038728/179855) for that which has been deleted by a moderator. Please explain me why it is deleted, as it's an answer for the question itself.

Comment: I'm surprised that the whole question wasn't nuked.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby why you want to nuke the question..?? Fetching address book is a very column thing. Check the framing of my question. I was having a problem and that I mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: "What is the best to do x", "Recommend me x" or "What application does x" are not good questions. There's a good possibility that they are open ended, unanswerable, subjective, argumentative, a mere list, something you should rather ask the search machine whom you trust and \*drumroll\* they are too localized, in a half year the answers might be overhauled.

Comment: I am wondering why your answer is nuked, though. Perhaps to prevent people from using your answer as an example and continue to reply to a not constructive old question

Comment: @nhahtdh the question does not fit Stack Overflow anymore - as you see, it's now closed.

Comment: I know that it is closed before I posted the comment. I'm just wondering why the answer was deleted.

Comment: @nhahtdh No, there is no such pre-emptive deletion of answers under the assumption that a question is no longer appropriate. The answer itself (which I can't see) must have had its own reasons for deletion.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby Invest 2 mins of the content of questions and answers. I have fixed the issue of the title. It should be reopened as I was supposed to paste answers for importing other address books.

Comment: So "I've found this plugin....I am still looking for other solutions." changes something? Additionally, it seems like you're pasting stuff which belongs in answers into the question...

Comment: Yes.. Cause that plugins ask for username and password. And I am sure people are not ready to give their usernames and passwords on some random site.

Comment: Anyways lets leave the discussion right here. :) I got the answer what I was looking for. I have one answer there. In coming time I will be updaitng the same answer :) Thanks for your time.

Comment: In addition to what [Tim said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144306/140951) about spamming your answer everywhere, why didn't you edit [the answer you *already* had on the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6409334/50776)?

Comment: @casperOne Please check my last comment :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311132/whats-the-best-plugin-to-fetch-gmail-yahoo-hotmail-twitter-and-facebook-conta/6311360#6311360) [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220589/importing-gmail-yahoo-hotmail-aol-address-book-with-rails/12038821#12038821) [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646547/rails-3-getting-gmail-contacts-using-omniauth/12038813#12038813) of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498795/how-to-get-create-an-access-token-in-ruby-on-rails-for-gmail-contacts/12038793#12038793) that [was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733576/how-to-import-mails-contacts-from-gmail-yahoo-etc/12038713#12038713) [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413623/how-to-import-contacts-via-gmail-in-rails/12038669#12038669). You pasted an identical answer on many different questions. It appears as if you were just trying to be helpful, but - if the *same* answer can sufficiently answer multiple questions, those questions should be flagged as possible duplicates and / or merge candidates.

If, in the future we were to merge those questions into one, *six copies* of your answer would then appear on the same (merged) question.

The moderator that deleted the posts was not taking issue with their *quality*, it was *quantity* that was the problem. The moderator that took action was just responding to a flag that the system automatically raises when it detects duplicate content.

I have restored the original answer on your question, and will look at a possible merge between all of the posts you found where it applies.

Comment: Note - Some of these are actually unrelated questions where the same answer is in fact helpful, I have undeleted a few. The real duplicate here is people trying to programmatically auth with Gmail using RoR, looking at that now.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation.Its cristal clear to me :) Will take care of this thing in future :)

Comment: Between question was closed because of inappropriate title (These title were good at the time it was posted, I have fixed the issue of the title, it should be reopened for future solutionsI was supposed to paste solutions for other address books..)

Answer (score -2):

Stack Overflow has changed. As time goes by, the volume of questions increase and major changes are needed to face those volumes while keeping the high quality.

Think of Stack Overflow being a city. It started as a cozy little village with few people living there and willingly helping newcomers to join. Over time great many people arrived and the village became a highly populated city. People are still welcome to join, but it's harder to keep everything organized, rules must be written and it can't accept everything anymore.

Bottom line - maybe your question was fine year ago. Not anymore - nothing personal.

Comment: Valid answer, though the question was, "why has my answer been removed"...

Comment: @Bart understood, on second and third reading of the question and my answer. Oh well..

Comment: Don't worry though. Downvotes are often used to indicate disagreement.... :p

Comment: @Bart really??! ;) The gray is too bright though.. grr!

Comment: I don't see what there is to disagree with here, it's a perfectly accurate historical account.

Comment: @Purmou Bart is right, it simply does not answer the direct question. :/ Hey thanks - assuming it's your vote that saved my eyes..

Comment: Oh, I know, but it's a refreshingly poetic way of not answering the question. I admire that.

Comment: @Purmou cheers, didn't know I have it in me! :-)

Comment: Well, the question _was_ closed as a result of the discussion, so good on ya for preemptive condolences.

Comment: @Tim actually it was closed before I posted this answer. *innocent whistle*